# Is there a way to filter by null value in an XML definition

Tags: xml, database

I am working on an XML Definition for my job essentially creating a list that will be sent via email that shows all the students without a login in our systems for grades 6 through 12 as that is when the student's gain access to our system however I am having trouble when it comes to actually filtering by the null values in there. I just don't know what is wrong here.

I expected that I would have all the students that don't have a user login but instead I get all the active students in grades 6 through 12. I have tried filtering it out by not containing an @ but some of the students have a username that isn't the email and it would be impossible to filter by every combination of letter. I have tried putting in null,empty,isNull,isEmpty,nil,and isNil (and various different variations of said list) but I don't really know what xml is looking for and every resource I find also doesn't seem to have a clear answer. I apologize if this is a dumb question but I am lost, I have been able to do most projects I needed to create decently easy but this is the first one where my lack of formal knowledge has led me astray.

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- XML definition for a simple export -->
<export header-row="true" table-id="tblStudent">
  <sort field="stdGradeLevel" direction="asc" />
  <filter field="stdEnrStatus" value="Active" source="constant" operator="equals" />
**  <filter field="relStdPsnOid.relPsnUsrOid.usrLoginName" value="" source="constant" operator="equals" />**
  <filter field="stdGradeLevel" value="6" and="12" source="constant" operator="between" />
  <field id="relStdPsnOid.relPsnUsrOid.usrLoginName" header-source="constant" header-value="Login Name" />
  <field id="stdGradeLevel" header-source="constant" header-value="Grade" />
  <field id="relStdPsnOid.psnNameLast" header-source="constant" header-value="Last Name" />
  <field id="relStdPsnOid.psnNameFirst" header-source="constant" header-value="First Name" />
  <field id="relStdSklOid.sklSchoolName" header-source="constant" header-value="School" />
</export>`
```

Comment: What kind of database? What are you using to filter? XPath? Maybe share the code that gives you "_all the active students in grades 6 through 12_".

Comment: @DanielHaley I am actually not sure off the top of my head. This is in an SIS we use called Aspen, it might be sql or XPath and I am sorry I just truly don't know on this. I have only been working with it for a month so I am sorry. As for the code that gives me "6 through 12 graders" I thought that filter by grade level was working but apparently that is also a problem and one of the projects I ran with that same line of code just happened to give me what looked like correct results randomly and continues to without it so I am on square one with that but I might just sort by school code.